# pre-commit config top level exclude doesn't work?

Tags: mypy, pre-commit.com

I have the following `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file. At the first line, I have this top level `exclude` path to exclude all checks in that folder, but for some reason, the `mypy` hook still outputs errors from files in that folder. Could someone help me understand what's going on? Thanks.

```yaml
exclude: "src/project/proto/"
default_language_version:
  python: python3.8
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.4.0
    hooks:
      - id: check-ast
      - id: check-docstring-first
      - id: check-executables-have-shebangs
      - id: check-json
      - id: check-merge-conflict
      - id: check-yaml
      - id: debug-statements
      - id: end-of-file-fixer
      - id: trailing-whitespace
  - repo: https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade
    rev: v3.2.2
    hooks:
      - id: pyupgrade
  - repo: https://github.com/asottile/reorder_python_imports
    rev: v3.9.0
    hooks:
      - id: reorder-python-imports
        args: [--py3-plus]
  - repo: https://github.com/asottile/add-trailing-comma
    rev: v2.3.0
    hooks:
      - id: add-trailing-comma
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v0.991
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        args: [--strict]
        additional_dependencies:
          [types-protobuf>=4.21.0.0, types-termcolor>=1.1.6, pytest>=7.2.0]
  - repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8
    rev: 6.0.0
    hooks:
      - id: flake8
```

I also have this `mypy.ini`. Just in case, I missed anything here.

```ini
[mypy]
python_version = 3.8
mypy_path = ./src:./tests

[mypy-lark.*]
ignore_missing_imports = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is working, but not in the way you expect

mypy performs dynamic analysis and will follow imports.  pre-commit is not passing those filenames onto mypy but they are being checked due to `follow-imports`

you will need to also use `mypy`'s settings to ignore errors there

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit